# Unity: Why am I getting an exception when reading a text file into a TextAsset?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a text file in Assets/Resources that I'm trying to read into a TextAsset. For some reason it's not being loaded, resulting in a null reference exception. This is the code:

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;
 
 public class LoadTextFile : MonoBehaviour
 {
     public string txtFile = "4.txt";
     string txtContents;
 
     void Start ()
     {
         TextAsset txtAssets = (TextAsset)Resources.Load(txtFile);
         txtContents = txtAssets.text;
     }
```

The last statement is where the null exception is reported. I don't understand why the file is not being loaded (I'm assuming it isn't), but it could be something else. The file is very small, as I'm just carrying out a test. Any help would be most welcome!

Answer (score 0):

The parameter to [Resources.Load](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html), should be the **fileNameWithoutExtension** and not **fileNameWithExtension**.

A note from [Resources.Load](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html) link stating:

> Note that the path is case insensitive and must not contain a file
> extension

So seems like just change

```
public string txtFile = "4.txt";
```

to

```
public string txtFile = "4";
```

Just a word of advice, prefer not to start fileNames with digits or symbols.

Comment: Thanks, but after making the change I still get the message about a null exception. I changed the file name to words4.txt in Resources. When that didn't work, I tried just words4. Still no joy.

Comment: @Pezza: The file inside Resources can have the extension. If you have placed "abc.txt" file inside __Resources__ folder, it will be accessed via `Resources.Load < TextAsset > ( "abc" );`

Comment: @Pezza: If you have created a folder __text__ inside __Resources__ folder and then added "__abc.txt__" file in it, we access it using `Resources.Load < TextAsset > ( "text/abc" );`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. My file is in Assets/Resources. I still don't understand what the problem is. It's the first time I've tried TextAsset, so I have no experience of it.

Comment: Problem solved! I'd been making changes without restarting the program. Consequently, it was acting on the original file name (4.txt). Your first suggestion, nIcE cOw was the answer I needed. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @Pezza : You're MOST WELCOME and KEEP SMILING :-) Glad it helped :-)